# iText PDF convert external images not reachable

Tags: java, pdf, timeout, itext, ping

I'm using itext 2.08 in my java application to convert html to pdf. But when there is a link to an external image in the html, the pdf conversion halts at line 7 in the following code.

```
                    1. File f = new File(fileName);
            2. os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
        3. String html = getFileAsString(new File(inputFileName));
        4. Document doc = getStringAsXMLDocument(html);
        5. ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        6. renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
        7. renderer.layout();
        8. renderer.createPDF(os);
```

So at line 7, renderer.layout(); does not get executed completely and I cannot view what line within the method layout() its getting stopped as its in a class file. I'm guessing as the application cannot ping the external url (of the image), its trying to ping it infinite times. So, is there any way to overcome this? Is there a way to set the timeout in case of itext pinging external sites images?